# How to manipulate regedit-key on a WIN CE 7 System

Tags: windows-ce, windows-scripting

I use a HMI Device with Win CE (Embeded) 7.0. My goal is to manipulate some keys of the registry editor by an automated script. At first I used .Bat and .cmd files, but this is not supportet.

Someone got an idea how to change this key with an other script?

Thanks in advance.

Frank